# Text alignment of Sencha Touch toolbar

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

How to left align the [My Toolbar](http://jsfiddle.net/JeaffreyGilbert/fAF23/1/) text through option (not CSS override)?

```
var myToolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({
    dock : 'top',
    title: 'My Toolbar',
    ???
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the layout of the toolbar

```
layout: {
    pack: 'justify',
    align: 'left' // align center is the default
}
```

This will change the layout of the buttons also (if any). You can control this behavior adding spaces between the title and the buttons. See this article for more details http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?102989-docked-toolbar-and-button-positioning.-align-attribute-is-ignored.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. Do you think you can modify the JSFiddle above to show a working solution?